# Swift get custom date (time)

Tags: swift, date, time, calendar

I have problem to get specific time from Date(). I have labels with time on collectionView. How i can get correct time?

This code allows me to get full data

```
private func recordUser() {

    let confirmationPayViewController = kMainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EVConfirmationPayViewController") as! EVConfirmationPayViewController
    confirmationPayViewController.modelController = MedicalRecordModelController()


    guard let selectedIndexes = collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems else { return }
    print("selectedIndexes: \(selectedIndexes)")
    for i in 0..<selectedIndexes.count {
        let indexPath = selectedIndexes[i]

        if indexPath.section == 1 {

            let date = todaysTimes[indexPath.item].start
            print("date: \(date)")  // date: 2018-07-31 14:00:00 +0000

            let df = DateFormatter()
            df.dateFormat = "dd MMMM, HH:mm"
            df.timeZone = TimeZone.current
            df.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_RU")

            confirmationPayViewController.modelController.medicalRecord.date = df.string(from: date)
            print("df2: \(df.string(from: date))")  //df2: 31 july, 05:00
        }
    }

    present(confirmationPayViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The date you are displaying in different date format so time is changed. If you want to same time as in date use same date format while you store date from API or any other sources...

Comment: @StepanValchyshyn i want to get same data on confirmationPayViewController.modelController.medicalRecord.date